# streamable api error: Failed to parse JSON

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

When I try to use the `streamable` API to create mirrors of twitch clips I sometimes get the following error:

```
ERROR: SnappyCallousSkirretSuperVinlin: Failed to parse JSON
(caused by ValueError("Expecting \',\' delimiter: line 38 column 76 (char 2027)",));
please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug .
Make sure you are using the latest version;
see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update.
Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

This error does not always happen, but I can't find any difference between the URLs that cause it and the URLs that do not cause a error.

My code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://clips.twitch.tv/SnappyCallousSkirretSuperVinlin'
api_url = 'https://api.streamable.com/import'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'clip bot'}
params = {'url': url}
r = requests.get(
    api_url,
    auth=('username', 'password'),
    headers=headers,
    params=params)
print(r.content)
```

The `streamable` API docs: https://streamable.com/documentation

Comment: how and where are you running this?

Comment: I get the link from reddit using [submission.url](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html?highlight=.url#praw.models.Submission) from the package [praw](http://praw.readthedocs.io) then I check if the url starts with https://clips.twitch.tv if so I execute  the above code. @user1767754

Comment: I run the script on a ubuntu 16.04 server using systemctl. @user1767754